# C#: managing large memory buffers

Tags: c#, memory-management, pixel

I am maintaining a video application written in C#. 
I need as much control as possible over memory allocation/deallocation
for large memory buffers (hundreds of megabytes).

As it is written, when pixel data needs to be freed, the pixel buffer
is set to null. Is there a better way of freeing up memory? 
Is there a large cost to garbage collecting large objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of garbage collecting large objects is very high from what I remember. From what I read they automatically become generation 2 on allocation(they are allocated in the large object heap). And since they are large they force frequent generation 2 collections.

So I'd rather implement manual pooling for the bitmap arrays, or even use unmanaged memory. Have some pool class and return the array back to it in the `Dispose` of your pixels/bitmap class.

Comment: as far as I remember files bigger than 75k are considered from garbage collector as unmovable and they dont belong to any of the three generations

Comment: I tend to disagree about large objects heap (LOH). The purpose why LOH was introduced is to reduce the cost of garbage collecting large objects. There are other rules applied to LOH compared to standard managed heap, i.e. GC doesn't compact memory in LOH, so there are no huge penalty for using large objects. I thing John Skeet or Eric Lippert or whoever will explain it better. Also Jeffrey Richer in his CLR via C# has whole chapter dedicated to managed heap.

Comment: While they are not directly part of the heap of a generation they are part of a generation in the sense that they are collected by GC runs of that generation. And from what I read(might be outdated) the LOH is only collected on Gen2 collections. I had some code that allocated about 10 objects with a few MB per second and that did not work well. Once I introduced a pool the problem disappeared. There is no penalty for just *using* large objects, but there is a big penalty for continuously allocating them.

Answer (score 3):

Don't throw big buffers like that away, you are lucky to have it.  Video gives lots of opportunity for re-use.  Don't lose a buffer until you are sure you won't need it anymore.  At which point it doesn't matter when it get collected.

Answer (score 1):

With memory blocks that large ("hundreds of megabytes") it should be relativaly easy to know precisely who and where uses them (you can fit just 10-20 of such blocks in memory anyway). As ypu plan to use such amounts of mmeory you need to carefully budget memory usage - i.e. simple copy of whole buffer will take non-trivial time.

When you are done with particular block you can force GC yourself. It sounds like reasonable usage of GC.Collect API - you done with using huge portion of all memory avaialble.

You also may consider switchihng to allocation of smaller (64k) blocks and link them together if it works for your application. This will align better with garbage collection and may provide more flexibility for your application.